# Python continuously write and save new data to file

Tags: python

I am trying to write data to file continuously to the end of file so that data becomes available for read as soon as it is written but it seems that changes do not get commuted without file being closed. 
I can open and close file every time script loops but I think its a bad idea and there must be a way to commit changes at the end of every loop

```
target = open("file.txt","a")

with open('test.raw',"rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(160)
    while byte != b"":
        byte = f.read(160)
        target_speech.write(data_value)
```

How can I get these changes committed inside the loop?

Comment: why use file, if people use it continuously , may be use database

Comment: Note that your code, as-is, is missing information. I'm assuming that `target_speech` should be `target` and `speech_value` should be `byte`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`target.flush()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush) immediately after `target.write(...)`

Comment: Thank you Jez, all of you guys and girls here have helped me allot to get unstuck when i run in to a unknowns. Really appreciate it